# Is it possible to set the python -O (optimize) flag within a script?

Tags: python, optimization, runtime, assert, conditional-compilation

I'd like to set the optimize flag (`python -O myscript.py`) at **runtime** within a python script based on a command line argument to the script like `myscript.py --optimize` or `myscript --no-debug`. I'd like to skip `assert` statements without iffing all of them away. Or is there a better way to efficiently ignore sections of python code. Are there python equivalents for `#if` and `#ifdef` in C++?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`-O` is a compiler flag, you can't set it at runtime because the script already has been compiled by then.

Python has nothing comparable to compiler macros like `#if`.

Simply write a `start_my_project.sh` script that sets these flags.

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    assert 0
    print("tada")

if __name__=="__main__":
   import os, sys
   if '--optimize' in sys.argv:
      sys.argv.remove('--optimize')
      os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, '-O', *sys.argv)
   else:
      main()
```

Comment: That's because you got the wrong arguments to `os.execl()`. The second argument is `arg0` not `arg1`. Try using `os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, '-O', *sys.argv)` or in fact pretty much any other string for the second argument and it should work as you expect.

Comment: @Duncan: I've fixed the arguments.

Comment: Great work-around! I never want to run without '-OO', so I made it into `if __debug__: os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, '-OO', *sys.argv)` instead