# Spawning a process with inherited python optparse options

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, optparse

I have a bunch of python scripts that use the optparse package. I'd like to give them all a "remote_run" option, which I'd like to use as follows:

```
if options.remote_run:
    cmd = create_cmd(options)
    os.system('ssh %s@%s "%s"' % (user, server, cmd))
    sys.exit(0)
```

The function `create_cmd()` should create a command that is equivalent to the command used to launch this process, except that the remote_run option is not set. The idea is for the script to outsource itself to a different server, in order to preserve the current server's resources.

What is the best way to do this? I did this one-off for a couple of the scripts by writing customized cmd-generating functions, but I have to keep those functions up-to-date whenever I add new options to those scripts, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Is it possible to set the python -O (optimize) flag within a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527055/is-it-possible-to-set-the-python-o-optimize-flag-within-a-script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
from pipes import quote

def main():
    print(socket.gethostname())
    print(sys.argv)

if __name__=="__main__":
   if '--remote-run' in sys.argv:
      sys.argv.remove('--remote-run')
      command = ' '.join(map(quote, ['python'] + sys.argv))
      sys.exit(subprocess.call(['ssh', '%s@%s' % (user, server), command]))
   else:
      main()
```

Comment: Great, this is clean and simple. I had been so fixated on constructing the command from the optparse object. This way is clearly superior. Thanks!